# How to store only US/Canada phone numbers in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, check-constraints, pattern-matching, regular-expression

I want to store only US and Canada phone numbers in a Postgres TEXT column. I don't want to use `pg_libphonenumber`.

What CHECK constraints should I be using for this purpose?

Comment: What are the rules the phone number should conform with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need  to get to grips with [`REGULAR EXPRESSION`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)s here. Now, PostgreSQL provides a [range of possibilities](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-matching.html) in this area and it is **well** beyond the scope of an answer here to teach everything about regexes - it's an entire area of computer science in itself - [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) is one of the better tutorial sites IMHO.

First things first - a phone number is a **string** (TEXT in PostgreSQL dialect  - VARCHAR() in others) - one doesn't add, subtract, multiply or divide phone numbers. Futhermore, characters other than 0-9 **may** appear in them (i.e. `(`,`)`,`-`, `.` and space).

As @LaurenzAlbe points out, it's good to have a clear idea of the actual requirement. So, you want a check on your strings to enure that they correspond to a North American phone number (all of the code below is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=cb341453b59a0988b6f932168ef37063))!

A North American phone number is 10 digits long, normally separated by a space into three groups of 3, 3 and 4 digits.

So, you can, as a first approximation, do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE phnum_1
(
  num TEXT NOT NULL
  
  CONSTRAINT num_1_ck_1 
    CHECK (num ~ '^\d{3} \d{3} \d{4}$')

  CONSTRAINT num_1_ck_2
    CHECK (num ~ '^[0-9]{3} [0-9]{3} [0-9]{4}$')    

 CONSTRAINT num_1_ck_3
    CHECK (num ~ '^[[:digit:]]{3} [[:digit:]]{3} [[:digit:]]{4}$')
);
```

Note that all three of these `CONSTRAINT`s do the same thing - just expressed differently.

These are **very simple** regexes (see below) and theyu just ensure that every entry for `num` must start with 3 digits followed by a space followed by 4 digits, another space and 4 final digits.

Explanation of the regex:

- `^` - is an `"anchor"` - it refers to the start of the string to be checked.
- `\d` (or [0-9] or [[:digit:]]) is shorthand for a numerical character - (i.e. 0, 1, 2... , 9)
- `{n}` is the way of saying `n` and only `n` occurrences of the previous thing - in this case, a digit - you can say, for example, `{2,4}` which means 2 to 4 occurrences of your match. In the above, you could use a redundant {3,3}/{4,4} if you wanted?
- then a space - the literal space character - it has no special meaning in regexes.
- then `\d{4} \d{4}` - 4 digits, a space and then 4 more digits.
- finally, another anchor - the `$` character which is the end of the string marker!

So, as you can see from the fiddle, `'123 345 3434'` is accepted as is `987 654 3210`, but `'123-234-5678'` is rejected.

So, this regex is simple, but very restrictive. Now, the levels of complexity for this particular requirement can become stratospheric very quickly...

There are opening and closing brackets (`(` or `)`) (intl code), `+` or nothing before the intl code), is the local exchange code a valid one, a hyphen (`-`) or not between groups of digits? Really, the possibilities are almost endless...

I would urge you to take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699007/regular-expression-to-match-standard-10-digit-phone-number/16702965) to see how some/many of these thorny issues have been dealt with on our sister site StackOverflow.

I've put some of these regular expressions into the fiddle as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE phnum_2 
(
  num TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

and populate it with some sample potential numbers:

```
INSERT INTO phnum_2 VALUES
('123-456-7890'),
('987 654 3210'),
('123-234-5678'),
('+1 123 456 7890'),
('+353 123 456 7890');
```

And then run this query:

```
SELECT 
  num ~ '\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{4}$' AS re1,
  num ~ '^(\+\d{1,2}\s)?((\(\d{3}\))|(\d{3}))[\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{4}$' AS re2,
  num ~ '^\s*(?:\+?(\d{1,3}))?[-. (]*(\d{3})[-. )]*(\d{3})[-. ]*(\d{4})(?: *x(\d+))?\s*$' AS re3,
  num ~ '^(\+\d{1,2}\s?)?1?\-?\.?\s?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{4}$' AS re4,
  num ~ '^(\+1\s?)?1?\-?\.?\s?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{4}$' AS re5,
  num ~ '^\s*(?:\+?(\d{1,3}))?[-. (]*(\d{3})[-. )]*(\d{3})[-. ]*(\d{4})(?: *x(\d+))?\s*$' AS re6,
  num ~ '(\+\d{1,3}\s?)?((\(\d{3}\)\s?)|(\d{3})(\s|-?))(\d{3}(\s|-?))(\d{4})(\s?(([E|e]xt[:|.|]?)|x|X)(\s?\d+))?' AS re7
FROM 
  phnum_2;
```

Result:

```
re1     re2     re3     re4     re5     re6     re7
  t       t       t       t       t       t       t
  t       t       t       t       t       t       t
  t       t       t       t       t       t       t
  t       t       t       t       t       t       t
  t       f       t       f       f       t       t
```

I would urge you to take a look at the ones which fail, and try to figure out **why** they've failed!

A couple of slightly less sophisticated ones are available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33158774/regex-validation-for-north-american-phone-numbers), a more complex thread can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/how-to-validate-phone-numbers-using-regex) and [this site](https://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=us%20phone&c=-1&m=-1&ps=20&p=3&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) provides lots of possibilities, including [this monster](https://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=18143):

`^(\+?1(-|\.|\s)?)?((\(((8(00|22|33|44|55|66|77|[8[0-9]))|900)\)|((8(00|22|33|44|55|66|77|[8[0-9]))|900))(-|\.|\s)?\d{3}(-|\.|\s)?\d{4}|(\([2-9]([02-9]\d|1[02-9])\)|[2-9]([02-9]\d|1[02-9]))(-|\.|\s)?[2-9]([02-9]\d|1[02-9](-|\.|\s)?\d{4}))$`

However, I'll leave the final word to this contributor who [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1245990/470530) that:

> If the users want to give you their phone numbers, then trust them to
> get it right. If they do not want to give it to you then forcing them
> to enter a valid number will either send them to a competitor's site
> or make them enter a random string that fits your regex. I might even
> be tempted to look up the number of a premium rate horoscope hotline
> and enter that instead.
>
> I would also consider any of the following as valid entries on a web
> site:
>
> - "123 456 7890 until 6pm, then 098 765 4321"
> - "123 456 7890 or try my
>   mobile on 098 765 4321"
> - "ex-directory - mind your own business"

Also, don't forget that regexes are **expensive** in terms of processing power - see [this article](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regex-performance/) from one of the founders of StackExchange and how to (partially) mitigate this from [one of the most prolific regex answerers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34675820/470530) on StackOverflow.

So, you really should consider your requirements - and how the eventual answer is going to be stored - as free text or strictly as a series of 10 [valid] digits? The cleaner your data is in your tables, the more potential you'll have for using optimising indexing strategies.